# Книга для изучения ассемблера

Tags: ассемблер, книги

Посоветуйте книгу для изучения masm32, подойдут ли для этого книги по Tasm?

P.S у одного меня проблема с кодировкой русских символов в заголовке темы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда-то читал книжку А.Крупник. Ассемблер. Самоучитель. 2005. Очень доступно написано и на пальцах все объясняется. Рассказывается, как установить и пользовать сам MASM, разные настройки, дебагеры и т.д. Конечно, все очень кратко, много нет, но для начала самое то.

Еще смотрел книжку Ирвин. Язык ассемблер для процессоров Интел. Очень понравилась. Думаю, стоит почитать.

Comment: Еще, для всех процессоров интел мнемоники будут одни и те же?
Смогу ли в последствии код написанный для masm, компилировать в tasm?

Comment: В masm32 и tasm32 мнемоники не различаются. Могут возникнуть другие проблемы, типа отсутствия нужных подключаемых файлов.

Вообще пользоваться tasm при написании программ под windows не рекомендую, поскольку он сильно устарел.

Comment: Спасибо скачал обе книги начал с 1, объясняется даже более чем доступно, галачку поставлю позже, может еще кто нибудь предложит какую нибудь литературу

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать книгу "Ассемблер это просто".
Наверное книжка довольно боянная. Но мне очень понравилась. Сам по ней изучаю ассемблер.