# Книги по Assembler x86 для новичков

Tags: ассемблер, книги

Какие книги посоветуете для изучения низкоуровневого программирования ASSEMBLER?
Книги желательно простые для новичков.
Спасибо.
Ах да, Assembler для x86.

Comment: Классика: Питер Абель - Ассемблер и программирование для IBM PC

Comment: По с++ литература вопрос с ответом не закрыт, а по ассемблеру закрыт, но он нужен, не так ли? Из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80 внятного ничего нету...

Comment: @nick_n_a Ну так надо эталонную закрывашку сделать и другие позакрывать как дубли. Кто этим займётся?

Comment: @nick_n_a, наверно, лучше будет новый вопрос завести. нормально оформленный.

Comment: Вопросов немного, вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35654/%d0%90%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2-linux вот с дублями https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563165/%d0%98%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0 вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/77615/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0

Comment: Остальные вопросы очень размыто спрашивают про ассемблер х86 и книги по нему, содержат более предметные темы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я изучал по [этой](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4579142/) . Мне понравилось.
Еще читал (правда еще в виде рассылки) [Калашникова](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5813688/)
Тоже неплохо. 
Еще понравились [витки](http://bitfry.narod.ru/). Правда это не книга.
Ну и WASM - наше все. Так что [статьи](http://wasm.ru/page.php?page=neophyte) для начинающих от туда - imho must read.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Финогенов. Основы языка Ассемблера. Учебный курс](http://m.ozon.ru/item/932265)
2. [Юров. Assembler: учебный курс](http://m.ozon.ru/item/140094)
3. [Юров. Assembler. Специальный справочник](http://m.ozon.ru/item/1660289)
4. [Зубков С.В. Assembler для DOS, Windows и Unix](http://m.ozon.ru/item/6597815)

Это минимальный список наиболее полезных книг для изучения с нуля. Учитывая, что ассемблер обычно подразумевает ДОС, то еще порекомендую справочную систему [Tech!Help](http://old-dos.ru/files/file_1067.html)

Answer (score 0):

Язык ассемблера: уроки программирования. Авторы: Рудаков, Финогенов. Книга хоть и не новая, но основы все есть - рассматривается аппаратная организация компьютера, работа с прерываниями DOS и BIOS, организация программ (в т.ч. и резидентных), вход в защищенный режим, написание драйверов. транслятор Borland TASM

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас приведу короткий список: во первых, можно начать с инет уроков Калашникова, потом почитать Рудольфа Марека: Ассемблер базовый курс. А дальше лети куда хочешь, в первых двух примерах хорошая база, написано понятным языком.