# Задания по Ассемблеру

Tags: ассемблер

есть задания по Ассемблеру. Но я в нем не бум-бум. Проверьте меня (ответы свои, дам через знак "=" )

1) Определить сколько байт памяти занимают переменные?

```
M dword 45 = 1
N word 23, ffh = 1
Arr byte "hello, world!" = 1
Mass byte 100 dup (23, "assembler", 0, 45h) = 100
```

2) Какие ошибки допущены при описании следующих переменных?

```
Text word " hello, world" = здесь я думаю пропущено в конце " ,0"
N byte 260 = неверный тип данных нужен word
M dword 24, ffh, 45h = здесь не знаю
K byte -5 = здесь мне кажется все верно
Arr word dup(76, 34) = мне кажется так же неверный тип данных, нужен dword
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал почитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/77802/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-assembler-x86-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2/131885#131885

Comment: хорошо  бы уточнить компилятор, а их много-много. Но в первой части точно есть ошибки. Скорее всего ответы будут такие 4,2,13 или 14, 100

Comment: Вот да, уточните компилятор и вообще для какого процессора (системы команд) ассемблер. | word - слово (обычно подразумевается два байта), dword - double word - двойное слово.

Comment: По второй части,  скорее всего word не поддерживает символы, неверный тип (0..255); `ffh` - не верно потому что `0ffh`. -5 не верно потому что (0..255). dup - возможно перед dup обязательно число.

Comment: `dup` повторяет всё, что написано в скобках (по крайней мере в известных мне ассемблерах). `23, "assembler", 0, 45h` - 12 байтов, значит `100 dup (23, "assembler", 0, 45h)` - это 100 * 12 = 1200 байтов.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Мне казалось, что -5 верно, потому что при гуглении, видел информацию что не только(0...255), но и (-128...127). Видимо не достоверная информация